# How to correctly import a macro from a user defined package?

Tags: package, lisp, common-lisp, asdf

I'm trying to import a macro defined in a utility package, but when I try to use the macro I get a message that says that debugger invoked on a `UNDEFINED-FUNCTION my-macro` and that `my-package:my-macro` is a macro, not a function. However when I call functions defined inside that same package I got no errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macro expansion happens at [*compile*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_b.htm) time. Your message indicates that the file that uses the macro was compiled when the macro was *not* defined, so the compiler assumed that the unknown name `my-macro` names a *function* (if you look at the compilation logs, you should see a message to that effect).

Solution: [`require`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_provid.htm) the file containing macro definitions in files that use them.

Comment: this is true, thanks, I was using asdf, and it results that I was loading the file with package definitions after loading the package that used that macro, I fixed it loading first the package definitions.